# What does the basis of $H^{\Delta}_1(T)$ look like? where $T$ is the Torus.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Using a $\Delta$-complex structure, I've calculated the simplicial homology groups of a Torus.

I used 2 2-simplices, 3 1-simplices and 1 0-simplex under the quotient map. I obtained the following groups:

$$H^{\Delta}_2(T)\simeq{}\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$H^{\Delta}_1(T)\simeq{}\mathbb{Z}^2$$
.

I understand that the $k^{th}$ homology group is the kernel of the boundary map  $\Delta^k\to{}\Delta^{k-1}$ 'quotienting out' the image of the boundary map  $\Delta^{k+1}\to{}\Delta^{k}$ but im having a hard time understanding what this means geometrically.

For example, in our case of the torus, could I draw on a diagram of the Torus the members of the basis of $H^{\Delta}_1(T)$ for instance. Is there a nice heuristic of what these homology groups are in relation to a given topological space.

EDIT:

or is it not really important, is it more that these groups are invariant when playing around with spaces that are topologically equivalent?

Comment: Hi, I think this link might help you. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/640/what-is-cohomology-and-how-does-a-beginner-gain-intuition-about-it

Comment: The phrase "the basis", which occurs both in your question and in its title, sounds as if you think there's just one basis. In fact, there are infinitely many. The simplest basis consists of the images in $H_1$ of the two $1$-simplices that are the sides of your original square. In the usual picture of a torus, one of these goes "the long way" around the torus and the other goes through the "hole in the middle". But there's another basis consisting of one side of the square and the diagonal. Visualizing that on a donut seems a good exercise.

Comment: Just for fun, there's another basis consisting of one side of the square plus a curve that loops twice around the long way while going through the middle hole three times. If you now imagine the latter curve staying put while the rest of the torus disappears, you'll have a knot (a trefoil knot if I remember correctly). Generalizations of this are called, for obvious reasons, torus knots.

Comment: Going back to the good exercise you mention, suppose we took the basis as you describe, would this look like then: one going all the way round, or going through the hole in the middle AND one going all the way round but also going through the hole too?

Comment: Sort of like a spring going around with torus, with 1 turn.

Comment: Yes, that's right.